# How to enable CSRF protection in Liferay

Tags: java, liferay, csrf, portal

I'm trying to enable CSRF in Liferay 6.1. I have this in portal-ext.properties

```
auth.token.check.enabled=true
auth.token.impl=com.liferay.portal.security.auth.SessionAuthToken
```

I also have this in portlet.xml

```
<init-param>
    <name>check-auth-token</name>
    <value>true</value>
</init-param>
```

Yet I can't see the p_auth parameter appear in the url as it should. Is there anything else I have to do to get this working?

Comment: CSRF protection is enabled by default for all ACTION requests (except for the *language* portlet).

Comment: It was turned off by someone else and I had to re-enable it

Comment: Then just delete the configuration.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Above configuration seem to be good to enable auth token.

p_auth parameter get added for all ACTION requests and still its possible to configure actions to skip authentication token using property "auth.token.ignore.actions"

Please make sure the URL that you are checking for p_auth is action URL and not included in actions specified for auth.token.ignore.actions.