# CSRF issue on liferay 6 CE on login page

Tags: liferay, csrf, owasp, zap, csrf-token

I am using Liferay 6.2-ce-ga6 with tomcat 7.0.62, I'm trying to update it and fix some vulnerability issues, according to OWASP security reports.

The tool (OwaspZap) reports to me problems with some urls with anti-CSRF token.

I have enabled CSRF protection for my portlet adding the follow code in portal-ext.properties:

```
auth.token.check.enabled=true
auth.token.impl=com.liferay.portal.security.auth.SessionAuthToken
```

I also added the follow code in portlet-custom.xml:

```
<init-param>
    <name>check-auth-token</name>
    <value>true</value>
</init-param>
```

My ZAP warning are like that in the picture
[(see "struts_action")](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hcwvk.png)

I also read this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28629279/how-to-enable-csrf-protection-in-liferay) and checked the `auth.token.ignore.actions` property in portal.properties file (inside portal-impl.jar).

I observed that the warnings in the ZAP report concern exactly one of the actions set in the property, `/login/login`

```
 #
 # Input a list of comma delimited struts actions that will not be checked
 # for an authentication token.
 #
 auth.token.ignore.actions=\
     /asset/rss,\
     \
     /asset_publisher/edit_article_discussion,\
     /asset_publisher/edit_entry_discussion,\
     /asset_publisher/edit_file_entry_discussion,\
     /asset_publisher/edit_page_discussion,\
     \
     /blogs/edit_entry,\
     /blogs/edit_entry_discussion,\
     /blogs/rss,\
     /blogs/trackback,\
     \
     /blogs_aggregator/edit_entry,\
     /blogs_aggregator/edit_entry_discussion,\
     /blogs_aggregator/rss,\
     \
     /document_library/edit_file_entry,\
     /document_library/edit_file_entry_discussion,\
     \
     /document_library_display/edit_file_entry,\
     /document_library_display/edit_file_entry_discussion,\
     \
     /journal/edit_article_discussion,\
     /journal/rss,\
     \
     /journal_content/edit_article_discussion,\
     \
     /image_gallery_display/edit_file_entry,\
     /image_gallery_display/edit_image,\
     \
     /login/create_account,\
     /login/login,\
     \
     /message_boards/edit_discussion,\
     /message_boards/edit_message,\
     /message_boards/rss,\
     \
     /my_sites/view,\
     \
     /page_comments/edit_page_discussion,\
     \
     /shopping/edit_order_discussion,\
     \
     /software_catalog/edit_product_entry_discussion,\
     \
     /wiki/edit_page,\
     /wiki/edit_page_attachment,\
     /wiki/edit_page_discussion,\
     /wiki/get_page_attachment,\
     /wiki/rss,\
     \
     /wiki_admin/edit_page_attachment,\
     \
     /wiki_display/edit_page_attachment,\
     /wiki_display/edit_page_discussion
```

I tried to remove that line and restarted liferay, but the ZAP warnings are increased and still present for that login url.

What am I missing? how can I do to resolve this issue?
Thanks

Comment: I don't see what you're missing but the screenshot you provided does not seem to include a anti-CSRF token, and the config snip you provided talks about session tokens which are not the same as anti-CSRF tokens....

Comment: In liferay all URLs will generate with one of the request parameter called "p_auth".
I know that "p_auth" is not in my screenshot, in fact I wanted to know how i can add it.
SessionAuthToken is default implementation class responsile to generate and validate token (see this link: http://www.liferaysavvy.com/2014/03/cross-site-request-forgery-csrf.html#:~:text=Liferay%20also%20implemented%20mechanism%20to,p_auth%20request%20parameters%20is%20included)
Thanks for your reply and your message. @kingthorin

Answer (score 0):

`p_auth` probably isn't one of the default recognized anti-CSRF tokens. If you add it via the [options screen](https://www.zaproxy.org/docs/desktop/ui/dialogs/options/anticsrf/) then you probably won't get this alert anymore.

You can read more about CSRF prevention here:

- https://cheatsheetseries.owasp.org/cheatsheets/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet.html

and CSRF testing here:

- https://owasp.org/www-project-web-security-testing-guide/v42/4-Web_Application_Security_Testing/06-Session_Management_Testing/05-Testing_for_Cross_Site_Request_Forgery

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion but I don't have "p_auth" in my form (look at my updated screenshot), I only have p_p_auth in the url (but not in the form), as you can see in my screenshot.
Do you know the differences between p_auth and p_p_auth?
Anyway, I have added p_auth (and p_p_auth) in ZAP-> tools -> options ->Token anti-CSRF, but my urls keep appearing in the alerts. @kingthorin

Comment: If the parameter is being passed as a URL value then it's leaked and not really safe as a anti-CSRF control. I have no insight into liferay so you'd have to dig into their docs to sort out the difference between the two params. You can read more about CSRF prevention here: https://cheatsheetseries.owasp.org/cheatsheets/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet.html and CSRF testing here: https://owasp.org/www-project-web-security-testing-guide/v42/4-Web_Application_Security_Testing/06-Session_Management_Testing/05-Testing_for_Cross_Site_Request_Forgery

Answer (score 0):

If you're running stock 6.2 GA6, you'll have [more than this single](https://portal.liferay.dev/learn/security/known-vulnerabilities/-/categories/113764209?p_r_p_resetCur=true&p_r_p_categoryId=113764209) issue.

Please consider upgrading and, in future, to stay closer to the current version. Also, be aware that there are occasional patches (I'm not sure if [this one](https://liferay.dev/blogs/-/blogs/security-patches-for-liferay-portal-6-2-7-0-and-7-1) is the latest for 6.2).

The safest way is always to stay close to the latest release. 7.0 was released in 2016, so you're already quite overdue - especially for internet-facing software.

Comment: I tried to install Liferay 7.4 and sent a ZAP attack. However my URLs are always signalled.

Comment: In that case, please provide a [mcve] (including your code).

Comment: If you try to install Liferay 7.4 (dockdocker run -it -p 8080:8080 liferay/portal) and OwaspZap (https://www.zaproxy.org/download/), even if Liferay is fresh and customization-free, you can see Token anti-CSRF warnings in OwaspZap attack. Thanks for your reply.